# Showing that $N(x) $ is a norm on $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $N: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow R$ s.t $x \mapsto \sqrt{x_1^2-x_1x_2+4x_2^2}$

I want to show that $N(x)$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R^2}$

I am having trouble showing that $N(\lambda x) = |\lambda|N(x)$ Indeed If $\lambda < 0$ Then N(x) doesn't exist and $\sqrt{\lambda( x_1^2-x_1x_2+4x_2^2)} \neq |\lambda|\sqrt{x_1^2-x_1x_2+4x_2^2}$     anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Prove that

$$\left(\,(x_1,x_2),\,(y_1,y_2)\,\right)\mapsto x_1y_1-x_1y_2+4x_2y_2=(x_1\;x_2)\begin{pmatrix}1&\!-1\\0&4\end{pmatrix}\binom{y_1}{y_2}$$

is a scalar product on $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ .

And by the way:

$$N(\lambda x)=\sqrt{\lambda^2\left(x_1^2-x_1x_2+4x_2^2\right)}=|\lambda|N(x)\;\;\text{in any case}$$

Not clear what you mean that if $\;\lambda<0\;$ then "N(x) doesn't exist" ...how come?

Comment: wait, isn't $N(\lambda x)=\sqrt{\lambda(x_1^2-x_1x_2+4x_2^2}=|\sqrt{\lambda}|N(x)$?

Comment: @SylvesterStallone There was a typo in my answer. It must be $$N(\lambda x)=\sqrt{(\lambda x_1)^2-(\lambda x_1\lambda x_2)+4(\lambda x_2)^2}=\sqrt{\lambda^2(x_1^2-x_1x_2+4x_2^2)}=|\lambda| N(x)$$